# Is there a call tree view available for jvisualvm or NetBeans profiler?

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, jvisualvm, jprofiler

JProfiler offers a live call-tree view so you can see what's using CPU in real-time and drill down for the details. Reset the counts to zero at any time, rinse, repeat.

I'm currently without that tool, and trying to get by with free/open alternatives. jvisualvm and the NetBeans profiler have a static snapshot call-tree and a live flat view. 
It seems to reason that there would a live call-tree view available (or as a plugin) but I can't seem to find one.

Is this sort of feature only available in commercial profilers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that no-one has mentioned a non-commercial version of this feature, and that I can't find one, I will claim the answer is:

As of the time of this post, this feature is only available in commercial profilers.

Update May 2012. I Still can't find anything.

Comment: do you really think this answer deserves to win the bounty?

Comment: As you can see, I asked this question years ago. I looked everywhere I could then. Asked coworkers who were familiar with NetBeans profiler, etc. After the bounty I decided to look again and it seems clear to me that STILL there is a live flat view and a static call tree view. http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html. My answer is as correct as it gets. So, YES. Until someone posts an answer proving otherwise, I do deserve to win the bounty.

Comment: Also, @shailesh, this answer predates the bounty by a year and a half.

Answer (score 6):

If you hit the 'Snapshot' button in the Sampler or Profiler windows after profiling CPU usage, it will show you a call tree with a summary of the CPU time for each method, along with self-times.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809814/952135

Comment: looks like this is also the case with NetBeans--you must take a snapshot first, then it will show you the call graph instead of just a list of methods.  Yikes, NetBeans.