# Getting breakdown of method execution time in jvisualvm

Tags: performance, profiling, jvisualvm

I am profiling a web application with jvisualvm. I can see how long various methods takes for example methodA takes 5 seconds... However, I can't see to double click this method to see where the 5 seconds is going.  I can "drill down" so to speak.

How do I achieve this in jvisualvm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you hit the 'Snapshot' button in the Sampler or Profiler windows after profiling CPU usage, it will show you a call tree with a summary of the CPU time for each method, along with self-times.